# Returning Dataset to controller in asp.net MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

In Data access layer I have method to retrieve all the table values. How can I return it into the controller in asp.net MVC. can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

```
public static Dataset GetMembers()
{ 
    //sql steps to retrieve records and fill it in dataset 
}
```

Controller code:

```
{
    var members = class.GetMembers()

    return View(members);
}
```

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific and maybe include some code. Could we see the code that retrieves your table values?

Comment: DAL code: public static Dataset GetMembers(){ //sql steps to retrieve records and fill it in dataset } Controller code: var members=class.GetMembers(){ return View(members);}

Comment: @Sivakumar Please include future code in your original post. It looks to me as if you're already returning it to your controller *and* sending it to your View. Did you mean to ask something else--maybe how to render it in your View code?

Comment: No David just I want to return the records as Ienumerable into the controller from the Data Access Layer

Comment: @Sivakumar What are you using in your Data Access Layer? ADO.NET, Entity Framework, Linq To SQL classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to modify your `GetMembers` method (or implement another one that returns `IEnumerable<YourType>`. In this example (since you don't provide any additional data), I'll return a list of `MyType`, which I'll assume looks like:

```
public class MyType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then populate a `List<MyType>` inside `GetMembers`

```
public static IEnumerable<MyType> GetMembers()
{
List<MyType> list = new List<MyType>();

using(SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    // get a DataSet as normal
    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        list.Add(new MyType()
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"].ToString()),
            Name = dr["Name"].ToString())
        });
    }
}

return list;
}
```

This is a basic example of how you could return IEnumerable (of which `List<T>` implements) from your method.